# CodeIgniter 2 and usage of $this->

Tags: codeigniter, variables, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 and have installed Ion Auth and also the News tutorial that comes with CodeIgniter.

In the News Controller, the element for the page title is written like this...

```
$data['title'] = 'Page Title';
```

However, in the Ion Auth Controller, the element for the page title is written like this...

```
$this->data['title'] = 'Page Title';
```

They both seem to work equally well, so can anyone explain the difference(s)?  Maybe Ion Auth was written for an older version of CodeIgniter?  Is there any practical reason why I'd want to use one over the other?  Please link to sources as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the author's preference.  He likes to use a class property to store the view's data.  It allows him to share it across methods.  If you look at the author's other projects (Source [1](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Standard-Project/blob/master/application/controllers/auth.php#L42), [2](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Standard-Project/blob/master/application/core/MY_Controller.php#L39), [3](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-MY_Controller/blob/master/MY_Controller.php#L49)), you can see two examples (source 1 & 2 goes together).

On a side note, for your project, this could allow you to extend the `Auth` controller with more view data.

```
class MY_Auth extends Auth {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->data['foo'] = 'bar';
        parent::index();
    }
}
```

That would allow you to use the `$foo` variable to your authentication view. (`/auth/index` in this case.)

In my own projects, I like to use a protected property for my view's data.  It does give you much more freedom than a local variable.  You don't need to pass the view's data as an argument all the time and you can easily extend your controllers afterward.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to use this  $this->data it means you can access  $this->data through out the class methods. On the other hand if you are using $data it is only available for the current scope or method and if you need data some where else then you will have to pass it as parameters to the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Adding $this on the data variable, makes it to be accessible through the class.

I believe the $data or $this->data is **only** used for "View". It will be passed from the "Controller" to the "View", so we can access that variable through the "View".

So, there will be no differences on the "View" side.

Comment: How do you mean, _"$this on the data variable, makes it to be accessible through the class"_?  Can you explain more?  I think I'm seeing `$data['var']` being used just fine in the class too.

Comment: What I mean it is accessible through the class is like this: Let's say we have function a(), inside it, we have $this->data['page_title'] = 'Test'; It means that $this->data is accessible from function b().

But it doesn't matter, we will just use either $this->data or $data with the same goal, to read it from View.